# Activating Feature Flags with Ember CLI

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I was reading the documentation [here](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/configuring-ember/feature-flags/#toc_enabling-at-runtime), and it looks like I should be able to activate feature flags like this in my `config/environment.js` file:

```
var ENV = {
   EmberENV: {
      FEATURES: {
         'new-computed-syntax': true,
         'ember-htmlbars-component-generation': true
      }
   }
}
```

Yet this doesn't seem to be enough, even after restarting `ember server`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, just found the answer. I had to be on canary to get access to the code. You can find out how to be canary [here](http://www.ember-cli.com/#using-canary-build-instead-of-release).